# save simulation data in python

Tags: python, save, simulation

I am doing a molecular dynamics simulation in Python with a large number of particles. Here I have to keep track of x-position, y-position, z-position, x-velocity, y-velocity, z-velocity, x-acceleration, y-acceleration,z-acceleration, x-force, y-force, z-force, potential for all 500 or 1000 particles along with the kinetic energy, potential energy, total energy of the system at every time interval. 
To save these data I am presently writing them to a file in the following way:

```
from numpy import*
...
f=open('myMD.dat','w')
while t<=tmax:
    s='%3.3f\t\t'%(t)  # writing the time to the file
    f.write(s)
    for i in range(TotalNumberofParticles):
        UpdateParameters()
        s='%8.3e  %8.3e  %8.3e  %8.3e  %8.3e  %8.3e  %8.3e  %8.3e  %8.3e  %8.3e  %8.3e  %8.3e  %8.3e\t\t'%(xpos1[i],ypos1[i],zpos1[i],xvel1[i],yvel1[i],zvel1[i],xacc1[i],yacc1[i],zacc1[i],xforc[i],yforc[i],zforc[i],potn[i])
        f.write(s)
        ...
    s='%8.3e  %8.3e  %8.3e\n'%(KE,PE,TE)    
    f.write(s)
    t=t+delt
f.close()
```

So if there are 500 particles, each line in the data file will have 7000 columns. It somehow seems a bad way of saving data. Moreover the simulation goes on for several thousand time steps. As the program proceeds it gets slower as well. Can someone give me an idea about how I can save my data in a better way? Also I would like to know how I can retrieve those data for further analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of writing each `xpos[i]` separately in a loop, write the whole array *in one go* with  [`numpy.savez`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html#numpy.savez);

```
import numpy as np

np.savez('myMD.dat', 
         xpos1=xpos1, ypos1=ypos1, zpos1=zpos1,
         xvel1=xvel1, yvel1=yvel1, zvel1=zvel1,
         xacc1=xacc1, yacc1=yacc1, zacc1=zacc1,
         xforc=xforc, yforc=yforc, zforc=zforc,
         potn=potn)
```

Using keyword arguments like this ensures that the arrays are saved with their proper name.

Since you want to write date for each particle *and* each iteration, I propose that you add an extra axis to the arrays to contain all iterations.

So instead of

```
xpos1 = np.array(TotalNumberofParticles)
```

do

```
xpos1 = np.array((number_of_iterations, TotalNumberofParticles))
```

You can use [`numpy.load`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.load.html#numpy.load) to read the data again:

```
import numpy as np

data = numpy.load('myMD.dat')
xpos1 = data['xpos1']
# et cetera
```

BTW, from [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) (the Python style guide):

> Wildcard imports (`from <module> import *`) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools.

Comment: I just have a query with `np.savez('myMD.dat', xpos1=xpos1, ypos1=ypos1,  ...  ..., zforc=zforc, potn=potn)`. Can I write this line within a loop because data for xpos1, ypos1, etc. should be recorded for all particles. And if so, can I give the same keyword name in each case?

Comment: @kanayamalakar I assume you mean you want to record data for all particles and all time-steps? I've changed my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pickle to write and read arbitrary data:

```
import pickle

a= [4,6,3,7,]

f=open( "testfile", "wb")
pickle.dump(a,f)
f.close()

f=open( "testfile", "rb")
b=pickle.load(f)
f.close()

print b
```